# How to increase the life span of my new router?

Tags: router, power, lifespan

I've bought a new router. I'd like to increase its lifespan as much as possible.

Should I turn it off while it's not in use to protect it from heat? Or Should I keep it always on to prevent surges that occur during turning it on/off?

While turning On/Off, Should I use its power switch (In this case, the adaptor will be still connected to the mains)? Or should I disconnect the adaptor from the mains?

Are there any other factors that directly affect the lifespan of a router?

Comment: A router is designed to be left on 24/7.

Comment: *"Are there any other factors that directly affect the lifespan of a router?"* -- HEAT.  Try to keep electronics cool and dust-free.

Comment: A few components used in electronic devices have limited lifespans: batteries, flash memory, things with moving parts (especially motors), switches, certain components of displays like fluorescent backlights, electrolytic capacitors.  Otherwise, solid state electronics can last almost "forever" unless cheap and defective (nothing you can do about that), or damaged.  Other than physical damage, the main culprits would be excessive heat (well above what it's designed for), excessive voltage, and excessive power-on cycling.  Aganju's answer pretty well covers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s a rather uncommon request, as routers are relatively cheap, but ok.

- For most electronics, the off/on cycle is the worst killer, so do *not* turn it off ever. You can do reboots/resets through software, which avoids that.
- Give it air flow so it doesn’t overheat. You don’t need a dedicated fan, but don’t bury it in a cabinet with boxes before it.
- Keep dust away. Install it in a place where there is little dust, and vacuum regulary. That is nomrally not an issues in lived-in rooms, but an attic or basement could be quite dusty.
- The typical death event for routers are brown-outs and lightning strikes. You can protect against them by having an UPS to buffer the power supply (that helps against brown-outs), and by having a lightning-protected power strip before it (that helps against lightning strikes in the neighborhood, but only once). Both options are typically more expensive that a new router, so it does not make much sense - but you asked.

Comment: I live in a country where everything is expensive or maybe I'm poor or maybe both :D That's why I wanted to keep my new router as long as possible. Thank you for your useful answer. I appreciate that :)